# duplicate cookies set by Google Analytics JS tracker

Tags: javascript, cookies

On the site www.biowishtechnologies.com/au/ we are experiencing an issue where Google Analytics is duplicating its cookies on each request. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicating"?

Comment: If you go to the site, and click through a few pages, then go and view your cookies (easiest in Firefox) you will see there are many many cookies with the same names, i.e. GA creates _utma, _utmb _utmc and _utmz. On my first request I get one set, on my second request I have 2 sets (8 cookies) on my third I have 16 odd.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. If you set up the same cookie name on different pages for the same domain/path (in my case ‘/’) then you end up with duplicate cookies with different values. I believe its IE8 bug. I ended up checking if cookie with the same name exists and if it’s then I delete old cookie before setup the new one. In your case I would let geniuses from google sort it out.